# How do I apt-get gddrescue and testdisk?

Tags: apt, software-installation

Gddrescue and testdisk are not on the 12.04 ISO that I downloaded and burned to a CD that I'm currently using to boot my system.  Where do I point apt-get to install those packages?

I have Internet access but got this results:

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package testdisk
root@ubuntu:/#
```

Answer (score 7):

Both packages are in the **Universe** repository. See this question to enable Universe repository :

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

In order to install them with the following commands you need an Internet access for your machine.

#### [Testdisk [image: Install testdisk]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk):

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

#### [Gddrescue [image: Install gddrescue]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gddrescue):

```
sudo apt-get install gddrescue
```

For installation without internet access see

- [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

If that is not possible you may also try with a live rescue CD remix that already has  these tools installed (e.g. [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage),  [TestDisk Live CD](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd))

Comment: I have internet access, got this result:    root@ubuntu:/# sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk
root@ubuntu:/#

Comment: See edit with link how to activate Universe repository.